# Using XSLT to copy all nodes in XML, with support for special cases

Tags: xml, xslt

Say I have a large XML file that the following structure:

```
<MyXml>
  <Data1>
    <Node1>1234</Node1>
    <Node2>abc<Node2>
    <Node3>gfdf</Node3>
    ...
    <Node10000>more text</Node10000>
  </Data1>
  <Data2>
    ...
  </Data2>
</MyXml>
```

I want to transform this XML into another XML that looks exactly the same, but has a certain string concatinated to a certain node, say **Node766**.  I am using an XSLT of course and wondering how I can tell it to copy everyhing as-is except for **Node766**, where I have to do something before outputing it.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<!--Identity template, 
        provides default behavior that copies all content into the output -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--More specific template for Node766 that provides custom behavior -->
    <xsl:template match="Node766">  
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            <!--Do something special for Node766, like add a certain string-->
            <xsl:text> add some text </xsl:text>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: +1 for a correct answer. I would put the identity template first.

Comment: @Dimitre good point. Putting the identity template first so that if any of the other templates have the same match priority, they "win" because they are last in document order.

Comment: Not only this, but if the identity template is at the top, it is most visible there and the code becomes more understandable.

Comment: +1: Same answer as mine, but with more work supplied.  Well done!

Comment: I used this sample in my code and it almost does what I need. The only problem I have is that:
 `<xsl:text> add some text </xsl:text>` is ADDING text to the existing value. How can I just replace that with the new text?

Thank you

Comment: @Steve Inside of the template matching the element that you are trying to customize, remove the apply-templates from inside if the copy, leaving just the content you want to replace with. The apply templates is selecting all of the attributes and child nodes and processing them with whatever templates match. In this case it is the identity template, which copies the matched node and then calls apply-templates for any of it's attributes or children.

Comment: This works, but it outputs only content (as string) from original XML. How can I make tags visible?

Answer (score 15):

Start with an [identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform), and include a template match for your exception.