# XSLT to convert unknown XML to CSV

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I am new to XSLT and have been struggling with the following problem. I appreciate if anyone could help me how to go around this.

This is my XML file, but the element names could differ each time. The XML is created on the run. Basically I don't know all the elements in the XML file. There could be more or less elements, but basically has the following structure:

```
    <University>
    <language>en</language>
    <name>Medi University</name>
    <location>Rome</location>
    <country>Italy</country>
    <member>
        <teacher>
                <name>John Sting</name>
                <joined>
                    <time>
                    <start/>
                        <end/>
                     </time>
                    <valid>true</valid>
                </joined>
                <name>Paul Ironman</name>
                <joined>
                    <time>
                    <start/>
                        <end/>
                     </time>
                    <valid>true</valid>
                </joined>
        </teacher>
        <teacherAssistant>
               <name>Luna Tutti</name>
                <joined>
                    <time>
                         <start>1.9.2015</start>
                        <end></end>
                    </time>
                    <valid>true</valid>
                </joined>
        </teacherAssistant>
     </member>
    <telephone>7538476398754</telephone>
    <email>medi@medi.com</email>
</University>
```

I have this XSLT file that tries to transform that. As I said the XML file is created on run time and I don't know the XML content.

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
   <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
      <xsl:if test="*">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above code prints the CSV file like this:

```
elemenNameelementValue
elemenName2elementValue2
elemenName3elementValue3
```

and so on.

What I want is something like bellow:

```
University

language, name, location, country,telephone, email
english, Medi, Rome,Italy,7538476398754,medi@medi.com

Teacter

name, joined, time, start,end,valid,
John Sting, , , , ,true
Paul Ironman, , , , , true

Teacher Assistant

name, joined, time, start,end,valid,
Luna Tutti, , ,1.9.2015, , true
```

I want related elements to appear on one line as in above.

Thanks

Comment: It's not possible to write a generic XSLT stylesheet that would fit *any* XML input. You have to provide some constraints, if you want to produce a meaningful result. In your example, you start a new "table" for `teacher`, but not for  `joined`. A truly generic stylesheet would not be able to make that distinction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this truly generic stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:call-template name="loop"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="loop">
        <!-- Output headers -->
        <xsl:for-each select="./*[count(*) = 0]">
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>

        <!-- Output values -->
        <xsl:for-each select="./*[count(*) = 0]">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>

        <!-- Process nodes having childs -->
        <xsl:for-each select="./*[count(*) != 0]">
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:call-template name="loop"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As mentioned by michael.hor257k, without some constraints, new table starts for each node having child nodes.

---

Try this for replacement

```
<!-- Process nodes having childs -->
<xsl:for-each select="./*[count(*) != 0]">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="name() = 'teacher'">
            <xsl:text>Teacher</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="name() = 'teacherAssistant'">
            <xsl:text>Teacher Assistant</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>

    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:call-template name="loop"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander. I will try this and see how it goes. Will come back here with results.

Comment: Thanks this worked great. By the way, if I want to replace an element name with its display name how would I do it? I tried this: <xsl:if test="name() = 'teacherAssistant'">Teacher assistant</xsl:if> after the first  <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>, but it prints both the element name and the display name. I want to replace the element name with the display name. Like if element name equals teacherAssistant, replace it with Teacher assistant. Thanks again.

Comment: Can't thank you enough. That's perfect. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the identity template (as in [Using XSLT to copy all nodes in XML, with support for special cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876382/using-xslt-to-copy-all-nodes-in-xml-with-support-for-special-cases)) and work from there.

As an example, with this code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">    
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
en
Medi University
Rome
Italy


            John Sting





                true

            Paul Ironman





                true



           Luna Tutti


                     1.9.2015


                true



7538476398754
medi@medi.com

enen
Medi UniversityMedi University
RomeRome
ItalyItaly


            John Sting





                true

            Paul Ironman





                true



           Luna Tutti


                     1.9.2015


                true




            John Sting





                true

            Paul Ironman





                true


            John StingJohn Sting





                true








                truetrue

            Paul IronmanPaul Ironman





                true








                truetrue



           Luna Tutti


                     1.9.2015


                true


           Luna TuttiLuna Tutti


                     1.9.2015


                true


                     1.9.2015


                     1.9.20151.9.2015


                truetrue



75384763987547538476398754
medi@medi.commedi@medi.com
```

(note that I had to put a final  in your XML

Comment: Thanks malarres. I know about the copying and that's what I did to get a copy from the XML file. The problem is that the XML file changes each time based on user's selection from the form. Elements differ each time, but structure almost the same.

Comment: I misunderstood the question. So you want to get the same output format no matter the current input, right? Can we count on having some fixed names for the nodes? <University> <teacher> <teacherAssistant> ...

Comment: Yes I want the same output format. The input format also has the same structure, except that some element names could differ; for example once could be <University> <teacher> <teacherAssistant>, next time could be <University> <researcher> <researchAssistant>. Or sometimes some elements or child elements might be in one input and absent in the next one.