# Converting generic XML to CSV (using XSLT)

Tags: c#, xml, csv, xslt

I need to convert xml to csv by  XSLT;
I don't know which tags inside xml, and also it contain duplicate tags.
example of xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AP     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    
 xmlns:pd="http://www.ascentn.com/bpm/XMLSchema">
  <processFields>
    <smsText />
    <PID>810C005056A14F7F119914B53474BB65</PID>
    <ComplexProximity>
      <lasttNameTxt>!!!!!!!</lasttNameTxt>
    </ComplexProximity>
  </processFields>

  <formFields>
    <txtTz>777</txtTz>
    <SubFormProximity1_SubForm>

      <SubFormProximity1>
        <SaleryAvg>10000</SaleryAvg>
      </SubFormProximity1>

      <SubFormProximity1>
        <SaleryAvg>0</SaleryAvg>
      </SubFormProximity1>

      <SubFormProximity1>
        <SaleryAvg>777</SaleryAvg>
        <SubFormIncomeSources_SubForm>
          <SubFormIncomeSources>
            <ddl_Sfs_fWorkStatus>aa</ddl_Sfs_fWorkStatus>
          </SubFormIncomeSources>

          <SubFormIncomeSources>
            <ddl_Sfs_fWorkStatus>bb</ddl_Sfs_fWorkStatus>
          </SubFormIncomeSources>
        </SubFormIncomeSources_SubForm>
      </SubFormProximity1>
    </SubFormProximity1_SubForm>
  </formFields>
</AP>
```

this xml converts to:

```
    smsText,PID,lasttNameTxt,txtTz,SaleryAvg,ddl_Sfs_fWorkStatus
     ,810C005056A14F7F119914B53474BB65,!!!!!!!,777,10000
     ,810C005056A14F7F119914B53474BB65,!!!!!!!,777,0
     ,810C005056A14F7F119914B53474BB65,!!!!!!!,777,77,aa
     ,810C005056A14F7F119914B53474BB65,!!!!!!!,777,77,bb
```

There is a way to do that with xslt? (note that it must be generic without write tags name by hard coded)

I need to export xml to excel (csv), so it's looks like excel export option. the columns name is tags name -only tags that not contain childrens. the rows comes from tags values, if there duplicates tags and different values its need to duplicate the rows with the different values. if inner tag (without childrens) is empty - the cell will be empty too

Thanks

Comment: Why is it that you repeat some data (eg. content of `<txtTz>`) but not other? What would happen if `,SubFormIncomeSources>` contains multiple child elements with the same name? You'll need to start by defining all of the possible supported structures. (And then what about mixed content...). You'll only ever be able to handle a small subset of possible XML documents: better to focus on useful input.

Comment: I guess it doesn't suffice to throw in one XML sample and one CSV result to explain which are the rules to convert XML data to lines of data in your CSV. What determines for instance that for some duplicated elements but with different values (like `SaleryAvg`) some values (like `10000` or `0`) are dropped?

Comment: @ Martin Honnen I edited my question.. with different values (like SaleryAvg) some values (like 10000 or 0) - Two lines will be formed in csv file. sorry about my mistake

Comment: _it must be generic without write tags name by hard coded_ Why?

Comment: @ lesscode because I don't know which tags I will get. its must be generic.

Comment: Can you try to explain in text what determines which values are put into one record/line of the CSV? Given your complex sample with various nesting levels I don't think it is clear which rules you want to implement.

Comment: I need to export xml to excel (csv), so its look like excel export option. the columns name is tags name -only tags that  not contain childrens. the rows comes from tags values, if there duplicates tags and different values its need to duplicate the rows with the different values. if inner tag (without childrens) is empty - the cell will be empty too.

Comment: Is the _structure_ of the XML at least going to be known or predictable (even if the tag names may change)? If you're talking about just any arbitrary XML you're going find yourself in a lot of pain here...

Comment: There are many answers to this question on SO. For example see https://stackoverflow.com/a/33970577/5045688

Comment: Why tag c#? PS: if you can really use this language, I would do it without xslt.

Comment: I am not familiar with Excel export options but in general I would think that it is easier transforming some non-Excel XML input to some Excel XML input format than trying to use CSV as an intermediary format. That single example however does not explain well how to map the XML, the input `<SaleryAvg>777</SaleryAvg>` does not seem to be represented in the CSV snippet in the question.

Comment: Before you can write any code you need a specification. XML is a far richer data model than CSV and there is no simple way of mapping arbitrary XML into CSV. If you want to handle any XML, then your mapping is going to be complicated and the result won't look pretty. That's especially true if the mapping isn't schema-aware, so that any element is potentially repeatable.

Comment: @ Alexander Petrov can you do it in C#?