# Setting node vale to specific string when it is null or empty using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt

I have the following input xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <GroupMainRequest>
       <GroupMainResults>
          <GroupNumber>GLEN01</GroupNumber>
          <divisions>
             <userProvidedEffDate>12/31/1998</userProvidedEffDate>
             <division>
                <GroupNumber>GLEN010001</GroupNumber>
                <GroupEffDt>01/01/2000</GroupEffDt>
                <GroupExpDt />
             </division>
             <division>
                <GroupNumber>GLEN010002</GroupNumber>
                <GroupEffDt>01/01/2000</GroupEffDt>
                <GroupExpDt />
             </division>
             <division>
                <GroupNumber>GLEN010003</GroupNumber>
                <GroupEffDt>01/01/2000</GroupEffDt>
                <GroupExpDt>12/31/2001</GroupExpDt>
             </division>
          </divisions>
       </GroupMainResults>
    </GroupMainRequest>
```

I need to update the value of the node `<GroupExpDt>` of each `<division>` under `<divisions>` to `12/31/9999` whenever the node value is empty or null( I am using XSLT 1.0).

The final xml output should be as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <GroupMainRequest>
       <GroupMainResults>
          <GroupNumber>GLEN01</GroupNumber>
          <divisions>
             <userProvidedEffDate>12/31/1998</userProvidedEffDate>
             <division>
                <GroupNumber>GLEN010001</GroupNumber>
                <GroupEffDt>01/01/2000</GroupEffDt>
                <GroupExpDt>12/31/9999</GroupExpDt>
             </division>
             <division>
                <GroupNumber>GLEN010002</GroupNumber>
                <GroupEffDt>01/01/2000</GroupEffDt>
                <GroupExpDt>12/31/9999</GroupExpDt>
             </division>
             <division>
                <GroupNumber>GLEN010003</GroupNumber>
                <GroupEffDt>01/01/2000</GroupEffDt>
                <GroupExpDt>12/31/2001</GroupExpDt>
             </division>
          </divisions>
       </GroupMainResults>
    </GroupMainRequest>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: "I need" is not a question. Where exactly are you stuck with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related to another question: [Copy all nodes with special cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876382/using-xslt-to-copy-all-nodes-in-xml-with-support-for-special-cases)

So upvote his answer too please ;)

Transformed his code a bit:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<!-- Identity template, provides default behavior that copies all content into the output -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- More specific template for GroupExpDt that provides custom behavior -->
<!-- Documentation below code block -->
<xsl:template match="GroupExpDt[string-length(normalize-space(text())) = 0]">  
    <GroupExpDt>
        <xsl:text>12/31/9999</xsl:text>
    </GroupExpDt>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[normalize-space() documentation](https://www.data2type.de/en/xml-xslt-xslfo/xslt/xslt-xpath-function-reference/alphabetical-xslt-and-xpath-reference/normalize-space/)

Comment: You could slightly simplify the template match to `<xsl:template match="GroupExpDt[not(normalize-space())]">`.