# Is there a simple way to copy an XML docuement, but change the format of date nodes?

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

My XSLT knowledge is still rudimentary, but I've figured out this much. Given a set of nodes, I can apply a template to select nodes, that changes the format of dates. Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/Data">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Worker"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Worker">
        <xsl:value-of select="LINE_NO"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="WD_BATCH_ID"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="./DATE_WORKED"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="./EFFECTIVE_DATE"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="HOURS"/>
        <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Worker/node()">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('20',substring-after(substring-after(.,'-'),'-'))"/>
        <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(., 'JAN')">01</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains(., 'FEB')">02</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains(., 'MAR')">03</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains(., 'APR')">04</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains(., 'MAY')">05</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains(., 'JUN')">06</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains(., 'JUL')">07</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains(., 'AUG')">08</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains(., 'SEP')">09</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains(., 'OCT')">10</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains(., 'NOV')">11</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains(., 'DEC')">12</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise></xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(.,'-')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This XSLT represents bit of a breakthrough in my understanding of XSLT, so I'm a little proud of it ;-) I like the fact that I can apply the date-format template to any direct child of `Worker`, and all I have to do is name the child node. This one happens to produce a CSV file.

I'd like to do something similar, but copy the XML, and without having to specify each node that gets copied, only the ones I want to have this date-format template.

Is there a convenient way to agnostically say "copy any given node in this XML, and if a node is named `DATE_WORKED` apply this template when you copy it? Alternatively, if there's some way that XSL can magically identify any date and just format it… that'd be cool to.

I have access to XSL 1, 2, & 3.0

I have in my mind something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/ | @* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="//DATE_WORKED" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Worker/node()">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('20',substring-after(substring-after(.,'-'),'-'))"/>
        <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(., 'JAN')">01</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains(., 'FEB')">02</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains(., 'MAR')">03</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains(., 'APR')">04</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains(., 'MAY')">05</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains(., 'JUN')">06</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains(., 'JUL')">07</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains(., 'AUG')">08</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains(., 'SEP')">09</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains(., 'OCT')">10</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains(., 'NOV')">11</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains(., 'DEC')">12</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise></xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(.,'-')"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...which doesn't copy the nodes, and only operates on "DATE_WORKED" nodes.

Yes, I've found this answer: [Using XSLT to copy all nodes in XML, with support for special cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876382/using-xslt-to-copy-all-nodes-in-xml-with-support-for-special-cases) But it would require making a duplicate template for each node that I want to format.

I'm working with XML that looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Data>
    <Worker>
        <LINE_NO>LineNo</LINE_NO>
        <INT_ID>IntId</INT_ID>
        <WD_BATCH_ID>WdBatchId</WD_BATCH_ID>
        <WD_PAY_INPUT_ID>WdPayInputId</WD_PAY_INPUT_ID>
        <DATE_WORKED>DateWorked</DATE_WORKED>
        <EMPLOYEE_ID>EmployeeId</EMPLOYEE_ID>
        <WEEK_END_DATE>WeekEndDate</WEEK_END_DATE>
        <EFFECTIVE_DATE>EffectiveDate</EFFECTIVE_DATE>
        <HOURS>Hours</HOURS>
        <PAY_COMPONENT>PayComponent</PAY_COMPONENT>
        <TK_COMMENTS>TkComments</TK_COMMENTS>
        <SS_REQUEST_ID>SsRequestId</SS_REQUEST_ID>
        <REQUEST_ID>RequestId</REQUEST_ID>
        <PROCESS_STATUS>ProcessStatus</PROCESS_STATUS>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <LINE_NO>0001</LINE_NO>
        <INT_ID>248697</INT_ID>
        <WD_BATCH_ID>kns_timeoff20191215_7_78593974</WD_BATCH_ID>
        <WD_PAY_INPUT_ID>248696</WD_PAY_INPUT_ID>
        <DATE_WORKED>25-NOV-19</DATE_WORKED>
        <EMPLOYEE_ID>101877</EMPLOYEE_ID>
        <WEEK_END_DATE>01-DEC-19</WEEK_END_DATE>
        <EFFECTIVE_DATE>15-DEC-19</EFFECTIVE_DATE>
        <HOURS>9</HOURS>
        <PAY_COMPONENT>Military AD</PAY_COMPONENT>
        <TK_COMMENTS>.</TK_COMMENTS>
        <SS_REQUEST_ID>78593755</SS_REQUEST_ID>
        <REQUEST_ID>78593974</REQUEST_ID>
        <PROCESS_STATUS>C</PROCESS_STATUS>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <LINE_NO>0002</LINE_NO>
        <INT_ID>248701</INT_ID>
        <WD_BATCH_ID>kns_timeoff20191215_7_78593974</WD_BATCH_ID>
        <WD_PAY_INPUT_ID>248700</WD_PAY_INPUT_ID>
        <DATE_WORKED>26-NOV-19</DATE_WORKED>
        <EMPLOYEE_ID>101877</EMPLOYEE_ID>
        <WEEK_END_DATE>01-DEC-19</WEEK_END_DATE>
        <EFFECTIVE_DATE>15-DEC-19</EFFECTIVE_DATE>
        <HOURS>9</HOURS>
        <PAY_COMPONENT>Military AD</PAY_COMPONENT>
        <TK_COMMENTS>.</TK_COMMENTS>
        <SS_REQUEST_ID>78593755</SS_REQUEST_ID>
        <REQUEST_ID>78593974</REQUEST_ID>
        <PROCESS_STATUS>C</PROCESS_STATUS>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <LINE_NO>0003</LINE_NO>
        <INT_ID>248699</INT_ID>
        <WD_BATCH_ID>kns_timeoff20191215_7_78593974</WD_BATCH_ID>
        <WD_PAY_INPUT_ID>248698</WD_PAY_INPUT_ID>
        <DATE_WORKED>27-NOV-19</DATE_WORKED>
        <EMPLOYEE_ID>101877</EMPLOYEE_ID>
        <WEEK_END_DATE>01-DEC-19</WEEK_END_DATE>
        <EFFECTIVE_DATE>15-DEC-19</EFFECTIVE_DATE>
        <HOURS>9</HOURS>
        <PAY_COMPONENT>Military AD</PAY_COMPONENT>
        <TK_COMMENTS>.</TK_COMMENTS>
        <SS_REQUEST_ID>78593755</SS_REQUEST_ID>
        <REQUEST_ID>78593974</REQUEST_ID>
        <PROCESS_STATUS>C</PROCESS_STATUS>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <LINE_NO>0004</LINE_NO>
        <INT_ID>1082611</INT_ID>
        <WD_BATCH_ID>kns_wd20191215_8_78593974</WD_BATCH_ID>
        <WD_PAY_INPUT_ID>WK1.1082611</WD_PAY_INPUT_ID>
        <DATE_WORKED>01-DEC-19</DATE_WORKED>
        <EMPLOYEE_ID>101877</EMPLOYEE_ID>
        <WEEK_END_DATE>01-DEC-19</WEEK_END_DATE>
        <EFFECTIVE_DATE>15-DEC-19</EFFECTIVE_DATE>
        <HOURS>7</HOURS>
        <PAY_COMPONENT>EWWHRWK1</PAY_COMPONENT>
        <TK_COMMENTS>.</TK_COMMENTS>
        <SS_REQUEST_ID>78593755</SS_REQUEST_ID>
        <REQUEST_ID>78593974</REQUEST_ID>
        <PROCESS_STATUS>C</PROCESS_STATUS>
    </Worker>
</Data>
```

Comment: Can you provide the input XML, please, to make a [mcve]?

Comment: Well, part of the point is that it shouldn't matter too terribly much what XML you pass it. I can copy ANY xml with the identity transform, right? I want to be able to do something similar, but with support for special cases. I've added the XML I'm working with.

Comment: To be clear, I want to be able to specify an arbitrary number of nodes, not just one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about changing your XSLT code to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <!-- Remove all space between * elements -->
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <!-- Identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Except for DATE_WORKED or WEEK_END_DATE or EFFECTIVE_DATE children -->
    <xsl:template match="DATE_WORKED | WEEK_END_DATE | EFFECTIVE_DATE">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('20',substring-after(substring-after(.,'-'),'-'))"/>
            <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains(., 'JAN')">01</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="contains(., 'FEB')">02</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="contains(., 'MAR')">03</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="contains(., 'APR')">04</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="contains(., 'MAY')">05</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="contains(., 'JUN')">06</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="contains(., 'JUL')">07</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="contains(., 'AUG')">08</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="contains(., 'SEP')">09</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="contains(., 'OCT')">10</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="contains(., 'NOV')">11</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="contains(., 'DEC')">12</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise></xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(.,'-')"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

Its output (for the example) is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
    <Worker>
        <LINE_NO>LineNo</LINE_NO>
        <INT_ID>IntId</INT_ID>
        <WD_BATCH_ID>WdBatchId</WD_BATCH_ID>
        <WD_PAY_INPUT_ID>WdPayInputId</WD_PAY_INPUT_ID>
        <DATE_WORKED>20--</DATE_WORKED>
        <EMPLOYEE_ID>EmployeeId</EMPLOYEE_ID>
        <WEEK_END_DATE>20--</WEEK_END_DATE>
        <EFFECTIVE_DATE>20--</EFFECTIVE_DATE>
        <HOURS>Hours</HOURS>
        <PAY_COMPONENT>PayComponent</PAY_COMPONENT>
        <TK_COMMENTS>TkComments</TK_COMMENTS>
        <SS_REQUEST_ID>SsRequestId</SS_REQUEST_ID>
        <REQUEST_ID>RequestId</REQUEST_ID>
        <PROCESS_STATUS>ProcessStatus</PROCESS_STATUS>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <LINE_NO>0001</LINE_NO>
        <INT_ID>248697</INT_ID>
        <WD_BATCH_ID>kns_timeoff20191215_7_78593974</WD_BATCH_ID>
        <WD_PAY_INPUT_ID>248696</WD_PAY_INPUT_ID>
        <DATE_WORKED>2019-11-25</DATE_WORKED>
        <EMPLOYEE_ID>101877</EMPLOYEE_ID>
        <WEEK_END_DATE>2019-12-01</WEEK_END_DATE>
        <EFFECTIVE_DATE>2019-12-15</EFFECTIVE_DATE>
        <HOURS>9</HOURS>
        <PAY_COMPONENT>Military AD</PAY_COMPONENT>
        <TK_COMMENTS>.</TK_COMMENTS>
        <SS_REQUEST_ID>78593755</SS_REQUEST_ID>
        <REQUEST_ID>78593974</REQUEST_ID>
        <PROCESS_STATUS>C</PROCESS_STATUS>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <LINE_NO>0002</LINE_NO>
        <INT_ID>248701</INT_ID>
        <WD_BATCH_ID>kns_timeoff20191215_7_78593974</WD_BATCH_ID>
        <WD_PAY_INPUT_ID>248700</WD_PAY_INPUT_ID>
        <DATE_WORKED>2019-11-26</DATE_WORKED>
        <EMPLOYEE_ID>101877</EMPLOYEE_ID>
        <WEEK_END_DATE>2019-12-01</WEEK_END_DATE>
        <EFFECTIVE_DATE>2019-12-15</EFFECTIVE_DATE>
        <HOURS>9</HOURS>
        <PAY_COMPONENT>Military AD</PAY_COMPONENT>
        <TK_COMMENTS>.</TK_COMMENTS>
        <SS_REQUEST_ID>78593755</SS_REQUEST_ID>
        <REQUEST_ID>78593974</REQUEST_ID>
        <PROCESS_STATUS>C</PROCESS_STATUS>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <LINE_NO>0003</LINE_NO>
        <INT_ID>248699</INT_ID>
        <WD_BATCH_ID>kns_timeoff20191215_7_78593974</WD_BATCH_ID>
        <WD_PAY_INPUT_ID>248698</WD_PAY_INPUT_ID>
        <DATE_WORKED>2019-11-27</DATE_WORKED>
        <EMPLOYEE_ID>101877</EMPLOYEE_ID>
        <WEEK_END_DATE>2019-12-01</WEEK_END_DATE>
        <EFFECTIVE_DATE>2019-12-15</EFFECTIVE_DATE>
        <HOURS>9</HOURS>
        <PAY_COMPONENT>Military AD</PAY_COMPONENT>
        <TK_COMMENTS>.</TK_COMMENTS>
        <SS_REQUEST_ID>78593755</SS_REQUEST_ID>
        <REQUEST_ID>78593974</REQUEST_ID>
        <PROCESS_STATUS>C</PROCESS_STATUS>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <LINE_NO>0004</LINE_NO>
        <INT_ID>1082611</INT_ID>
        <WD_BATCH_ID>kns_wd20191215_8_78593974</WD_BATCH_ID>
        <WD_PAY_INPUT_ID>WK1.1082611</WD_PAY_INPUT_ID>
        <DATE_WORKED>2019-12-01</DATE_WORKED>
        <EMPLOYEE_ID>101877</EMPLOYEE_ID>
        <WEEK_END_DATE>2019-12-01</WEEK_END_DATE>
        <EFFECTIVE_DATE>2019-12-15</EFFECTIVE_DATE>
        <HOURS>7</HOURS>
        <PAY_COMPONENT>EWWHRWK1</PAY_COMPONENT>
        <TK_COMMENTS>.</TK_COMMENTS>
        <SS_REQUEST_ID>78593755</SS_REQUEST_ID>
        <REQUEST_ID>78593974</REQUEST_ID>
        <PROCESS_STATUS>C</PROCESS_STATUS>
    </Worker>
</Data>
```

The output for the first item is wrong, so you need to make an exceptiion rule. But the rest does fit.

Also, in XSLT-3.0 the *Identity template*  can be replaced by the element

```
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" />
```

And to make it even more general, you could use the template matching rule

```
<xsl:template match="*[contains(local-name(),'DATE')]">
```

which matches all elements whose names contain the string 'DATE'.

Comment: Close, but this has the same problem as the answer I referenced: I have to create a separate template for each date node that I want to format. In my example, "Worker/node()" will match any child of Worker, so to format every each different date field, I just have to call "<xsl:apply-templates select="......"/>" for ay given node.

Comment: Well, yes, this is what XSL templates do. But there's still not emerging a pattern that distincts the matching elements from the non-matching ones.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I have a template that matches any node. I have a template that matches any child of Worker. I want to be able to copy any node, unless it matches child of worker, and then name some specific children of Worker that should be selected for that match.

Comment: I know all the PIECES are possible, I just can't figure out how to put them together the way I'm thinking. It might not be possible.

Comment: I updated my answer. Exclude the elements you want to match from the general exclusion rule - like in the answer above - and then the result should be fine.

Comment: Again, this doesn't solve the problem of having to create a duplicate template for every node you want to format (one for `DATE_WORKED` and one for `EFFECTIVE_DATE` and one for `WEEK_END_DATE`). That's the value of `<xsl:template match="Worker/node()">` it allows me to select ANY of the children of Worker for this template. I just don't know how to specifically select a node like `<xsl:apply-templates select="./DATE_WORKED"/>` without breaking the identity template.

Comment: I hope that I now fully understood your question. I updated my answer again.

Comment: OH!! Now I see what you're doing. Yeah! I think that is exactly what I'm looking for! Let me test it out and get back to you.

Comment: YEAH!! That's it! Thanks! Sorry it took me a while to catch on to what you were doing. The 'or' operation should have been obvious to me.

Answer (score 1):

As a supplement to the answer from @zx485, if you want to avoid the ugly `xsl:choose`, you could try

```
<xsl:function name="f:month-number" as="xs:integer?">
  <xsl:param name="month-abbr" as="xs:string"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="index-of(('JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', ...), $month-abbr)"/>
</xsl:function>
```

and then use format-integer() to format the result as two digits.