# Using XSLT to copy all nodes in XML, while transforming nodes with a specific sibling value

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have an xml file that I need to mostly copy 1 for 1 except for 1 node with a specific value that I need to transform. My XML looks like this:

> ```
> <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
> <xyz:Workers xmlns:xyz="urn:com.website/xyz">
>     <xyz:Worker>
>         <xyz:Effective_Change xyz:Sequence="0">
>             <xyz:Person_Identification xyz:isAdded="1">
>                 <xyz:Identifier>
>                     <xyz:ID>MJ 12 34 56 Z</xyz:ID>
>                     <xyz:IdType>A Type</xyz:IdType>
>                 </xyz:Identifier>
>             </xyz:Person_Identification>
>         </xyz:Effective_Change>
>     </xyz:Worker>
>     <xyz:Worker>
>         <xyz:Effective_Change xyz:Sequence="0">
>             <xyz:Person_Identification xyz:isUpdated="1">
>                 <xyz:Identifier xyz:isUpdated="1">
>                     <xyz:ID>JHQ123</xyz:ID>
>                     <xyz:IdType>B Type</xyz:IdType>
>                 </xyz:Identifier>
>                 <xyz:Identifier xyz:isUpdated="1">
>                     <xyz:ID xyz:priorValue="555-55-5555">123-45-6789</xyz:ID>
>                     <xyz:IdType>C Type</xyz:IdType>
>                 </xyz:Identifier>
>             </xyz:Person_Identification>
>         </xyz:Effective_Change>
>     </xyz:Worker>
> </xyz:Workers>
> ```
>
> I need to take the value loaded in node xyz:ID
>
> ```
>  <xyz:ID>MJ 12 34 56 Z</xyz:ID>
> ```
>
> And strip the white space so it looks like this:
>
> ```
>  <xyz:ID>MJ123456Z</xyz:ID>
> ```
>
> But only when their sibling node is xyz:IdType = A Type
>
> ```
>  <xyz:IdType>A Type</xyz:IdType>
> ```

Here is the XSLT I tried. I referenced this stack overflow ([Using XSLT to copy all nodes in XML, with support for special cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876382/using-xslt-to-copy-all-nodes-in-xml-with-support-for-special-cases)) but after working on it, I'm unsure if this is the right approach.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:this="urn:this-stylesheet"
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   xmlns:xyz="urn:com.website/xyz" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs this">
    <!--Identity template, 
        provides default behavior that copies all content into the output -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
   
    <xsl:template match="xyz:ID">  
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="translate(node(), ' ', '')"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This XSLT gives me the below output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xyz:Workers xmlns:xyz="urn:com.website/xyz">
    <xyz:Worker>
        <xyz:Effective_Change xyz:Sequence="0">
            <xyz:Person_Identification xyz:isAdded="1">
                <xyz:Identifier>
                    <xyz:ID>MJ123456Z</xyz:ID>
                    <xyz:IdType>A Type</xyz:IdType>
                </xyz:Identifier>
            </xyz:Person_Identification>
        </xyz:Effective_Change>
    </xyz:Worker>
    <xyz:Worker>
        <xyz:Effective_Change xyz:Sequence="0">
            <xyz:Person_Identification xyz:isUpdated="1">
                <xyz:Identifier xyz:isUpdated="1">
                    <xyz:ID>JHQ123</xyz:ID>
                    <xyz:IdType>B Type</xyz:IdType>
                </xyz:Identifier>
                <xyz:Identifier xyz:isUpdated="1">
                    <xyz:ID>123-45-6789</xyz:ID>
                    <xyz:IdType>C Type</xyz:IdType>
                </xyz:Identifier>
            </xyz:Person_Identification>
        </xyz:Effective_Change>
    </xyz:Worker>
</xyz:Workers>
```

Which is close to the desired output, because it did strip the white space from the desired ID:

```
 <xyz:ID>MJ123456Z</xyz:ID>
```

But, on the C Type Identifier, it is removing the data loaded in the Tag:

Before Transformation:

```
 
 <xyz:ID xyz:priorValue="555-55-5555">123-45-6789</xyz:ID>
 <xyz:IdType>C Type</xyz:IdType>
```

After transformation:

```
 <xyz:ID>123-45-6789</xyz:ID>
 <xyz:IdType>C Type</xyz:IdType>
```

This is an issue as I want the rest of the file to be identical except for ID's where sibling ID type = A Type.

I believe this has to do something with the template match applying itself to all of the ID nodes. I tried doing something along this logic:

```
   <xsl:template match="xyz:Identifier[xyz:IdType='A Type']">
```

But had no luck. Any leads on where to start or the kind of logic I should be using would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But only when their sibling node is xyz:ID_Type = A Type

You can use a predicate on `xyz:Identifier` for this. Note though that you say `xyz:ID_Type` but the example has `xyz:IdType`.

I'd also just match `text()` so you don't have to copy or apply-templates to the attributes of `xyz:ID`.

Try changing your last template to (change `IdType` to `ID_Type` if needed for your actual data):

```xml
<xsl:template match="xyz:Identifier[xyz:IdType='A Type']/xyz:ID/text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="translate(., ' ', '')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbUWwbs

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following XSLT.

It seems that your XML sample should have instead of:

```
<xyz:IdType>A Type</xyz:IdType>
```

the following:

```
<xyz:ID_Type>A Type</xyz:ID_Type>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xyz="urn:com.website/xyz">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"
                omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!--Identity Transform pattern-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xyz:ID[following-sibling::xyz:ID_Type='A Type']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="translate(., ' ', '')"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<xyz:Workers xmlns:xyz="urn:com.website/xyz">
  <xyz:Worker>
    <xyz:Effective_Change xyz:Sequence="0">
      <xyz:Person_Identification xyz:isAdded="1">
        <xyz:Identifier>
          <xyz:ID>MJ123456Z</xyz:ID>
          <xyz:ID_Type>A Type</xyz:ID_Type>
        </xyz:Identifier>
      </xyz:Person_Identification>
    </xyz:Effective_Change>
  </xyz:Worker>
  <xyz:Worker>
    <xyz:Effective_Change xyz:Sequence="0">
      <xyz:Person_Identification xyz:isUpdated="1">
        <xyz:Identifier xyz:isUpdated="1">
          <xyz:ID>JHQ123</xyz:ID>
          <xyz:ID_Type>B Type</xyz:ID_Type>
        </xyz:Identifier>
        <xyz:Identifier xyz:isUpdated="1">
          <xyz:ID xyz:priorValue="555-55-5555">123-45-6789</xyz:ID>
          <xyz:ID_Type>C Type</xyz:ID_Type>
        </xyz:Identifier>
      </xyz:Person_Identification>
    </xyz:Effective_Change>
  </xyz:Worker>
</xyz:Workers>
```

Comment: If `xyz:ID` had any attributes, you'd still lose them.

Comment: See: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbUWwbs/1 I added an attribute to the `xyz:ID` and changed `xyz:IdType` to `xyz:ID_Type` so your stylesheet would work. Notice it dropped the attribute I added.

Comment: My sincere apologies for adding confusion with my example. I have edited so that all of the nodes for type are "xyz:IdType". I checkmarked the solution based on Daniel indicating that if other nodes had attributes that they would get dropped. 

Thank you both very much.